# Two FTP users with permissions within the same path

Tags: linux, ftp, debian, chmod, chown

I'm trying to figure out how to setup two users with full access to the same path eg.:

User: **user1** Home: **/var/www/user1website.com/public_html/**

User: **user 2** Home: **/var/www/user1website.com/public_html/uploads/files/**

I need **user1** to be able to access (modify, read, write, exec) all files in /var/www/user1website.com/public_html/*, and **user 2** to be able access (modify, read, write, exec) only /var/www/user1website.com/public_html/uploads/files/. E.g. user2 has uploaded and updated a file called 20120513.txt in /var/www/user1website.com/public_html/uploads/files/20120513.txt. Now user1 can access same file /var/www/user1website.com/public_html/uploads/files/20120513.txt with full permissions.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add user1 to group that user2 belongs to.
Usually group name has the same name as username.
You can use it manually by editing /etc/groups file or usermod -G utility.